# How do I wait for an exec process to finish in Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have the following test, but I can't seem to get Jest to wait for my exec call to finish running:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

test('render', async () => {
    await exec('./render.local.sh', (err, out) => {
        console.log(err, out)
        expect(...some file to be created)
    });
})
```

What should I do to make jest wait for the exec callback to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `done()` after your assertion.

```
test('render', async (done) => {
    await exec('./render.local.sh', (err, out) => {
        console.log(err, out);
        expect(...some file to be created);
        done();
    });
})
```

Which will mark the test to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility I found that works with `async`

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

test('render', async () => {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('./render.local.sh');

    console.log(stdout, stderr);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of putting the test in a function with an empty argument, use a single argument called `done`. Jest will wait until the `done` callback is called before finishing the test.

```js
test('render', done => {
    exec('./render.local.sh', (err, out) => {
        console.log(err, out);
        try {
            expect('what you want to check').toBe('expected result');
            done();
        } catch (e) {
            done(e);
        }
    });
});
```

> If `done()` is never called, the test will fail (with timeout error), which is what you want to happen.

> If the `expect` statement fails, it throws an error and `done()` is not called. If we want to see in the test log why it failed, we have to wrap `expect` in a try block and pass the error in the `catch` block to `done`. Otherwise, we end up with an opaque timeout error that doesn't show what value was received by `expect(data)`.

According to the official [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous).